# Mastermind in Rust

Tags: rust

To learn Rust I coded a clone of Mastermind.

Mastermind is a 2-player game, where a master chooses a combination of 4 pegs which are of 6 different colors (For example : Red Yellow Blue Red)

The other player has 12 turns to try to guess the master combination.
Each turn, the player does a guess of 4 pegs. (Exemple : Red Blue White Green)

- if one peg is of the right color and at the right place, the master puts on red code-peg (In the example the first and red peg is of the right color and at the right place)
- if one peg is of the right color but not at the right place, the master puts on white code-peg (In the example the second and blue peg is of the right color but not at the right place)

With this information, the player tries another guess.

My code works this way :

1. Generate an array of 4 random number between 1 and 6 (which represent the six colors)
2. Get and parse user input, in this format : "2 3 6 5"
3. Compare the player's guess with the master's code and compute the number of white and red code-pegs

The code can be found here, in the develop branch : https://github.com/ElevenJune/mastermind_Rust/tree/develop
(The tag v0.2 is the same code but with a GUI in Slint)

This is my first code in Rust and I would like to know :

- If the implementation seems safe and the types (arrays) are well chosen
- If some action could be done in a more sexy or effective way

Thanks in advance !

Inline code :

```
use rand::Rng;
use std::io;

const NUMBER_OF_PINS : i32 = 4;
const NUMBER_OF_COLORS : i32 = 6;
const MAX_TURN : i32 = 12;
static DEFAULT_HAND : [i32;NUMBER_OF_PINS as usize] = [0;NUMBER_OF_PINS as usize];

struct Pins {
    red: i32,
    white: i32
}

impl Pins {
    fn print(&self) {
        println!("Red pins: {}, white pins: {}", self.red, self.white);
    }
}


fn main() {

    //Generate master's hand
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let master:[i32;NUMBER_OF_PINS as usize] = [(); NUMBER_OF_PINS as usize].map(|_| rng.gen_range(1..NUMBER_OF_COLORS+1));
    let mut count = 1;
    print_rules();

    loop {
        println!("--- TURN n°{} ---",count);
        let (user_hand, stop) = get_user_hand();
        if stop { break;}

        let pins = compare_hands(&master,&user_hand);
        pins.print();
        if pins.red == NUMBER_OF_PINS {
            println!("You won ! The solution was :");
            print_line(master);
            break;
        }
        if count == MAX_TURN {
            println!("You lost ! The solution was :");
            print_line(master);
            break;
        }
        count+=1;
    }
    
}

//Prints [i32,NUMBER_OF_PINS]
fn print_line(list:[i32;NUMBER_OF_PINS as usize]) {
    println! ("{:?}", list);
}

//Returns user's hand as [i32;NUMBER_OF_PINS] and a stop bool that is true is the user asked to quit
fn get_user_hand() -> ([i32;NUMBER_OF_PINS as usize],bool) {
    //Get user input
    let mut guess = String::new();

    loop {

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut guess)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    if guess.trim().eq("quit"){
        return (DEFAULT_HAND,true);
    }

    let (user_hand, error) = parse_user_input(&guess);

    if !error {
            return (user_hand,false);
        } else {
            println!("You should enter {} digits, seperated by a space, in the range 1 - {}",NUMBER_OF_PINS, NUMBER_OF_COLORS);
            println!("Type \"quit\" if you wish to stop the game");
            guess.clear();
        }
    }
}

fn parse_user_input(guess:&str) -> ([i32;NUMBER_OF_PINS as usize],bool) {
    let split = guess.split(' ');
    let mut array = [0;NUMBER_OF_PINS as usize];

    //Parse each number, stop if there are letters or out of range numbers
    let mut i = 0;
    for s in split {
        let num:i32 = match s.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => {return (DEFAULT_HAND,true);},
        };
        if num <= 0 || num >NUMBER_OF_COLORS {
            return (DEFAULT_HAND,true);
        }

        if i >= NUMBER_OF_PINS as usize{
            break;
        }
        array[i]=num;
        i+=1;
    }
    let len_ok : bool = i >= NUMBER_OF_PINS as usize;
    if len_ok {
        return (array,false)
    } else 
    {
        return (DEFAULT_HAND,true)
    };
}

//red pin if good color in right spot
//white if good color but not good spot
//Compares the user'hand with the master's code and return a Pins struct
fn compare_hands(master:&[i32;NUMBER_OF_PINS as usize],user:&[i32;NUMBER_OF_PINS as usize]) -> Pins{
    let len = master.len();
    let mut red_pin = 0;
    let mut white_pin = 0;
    let mut master_treated : [i32;NUMBER_OF_PINS as usize] = [0; NUMBER_OF_PINS as usize];
    let mut user_treated : [i32;NUMBER_OF_PINS as usize] = [0; NUMBER_OF_PINS as usize];

    //Compute red pins
    for i in 0..len {
        if user[i]==master[i] && master_treated[i]==0 {
            red_pin+=1;
            master_treated[i]=1;
            user_treated[i]=1;
        }
    }
    
    //Compute white pins
    for i in 0..len {
        for j in 0..len{
            if master_treated[j]==0 && user_treated[i]==0 && user[i]==master[j] {
                white_pin+=1;
                master_treated[j]=1;
                user_treated[i]=1;
            }
            //print_line(master_treated);
        }
    }

    Pins{red:red_pin,white:white_pin}
}

fn print_rules() {
    let mut format = String::new();
    for i in 0..NUMBER_OF_PINS{
        let num = format!("{}{}",i.to_string(), if i!=NUMBER_OF_PINS-1 {" "} else {""});
        format.push_str(&num);
    }
    println!("--- Mastermind ---");
    println!("- Rules :");
    println!("-     Find the master's code, made up of 5 digits from 1 to 8 ");
    println!("-     You have 12 tries, if you fail to discover the master's code in less than 12 tries you loose");
    println!("-     At each turn, you enter your guess in the format \"{}\" (your digits are to be seperated by a space)",format);
    println!("-     The master will give you a hint about how close is your guess from his code with pins :");
    println!("-         - A red pin means that one of the digit you chose is the right one and is in the right spot");
    println!("-         - A white pin means that one of the digit you chose is present in his code, but not at the right spot");
    println!("-     Good luck !");
    println!("You should enter {} digits, seperated by a space, in the range 1 - {}",NUMBER_OF_PINS, NUMBER_OF_COLORS);
    println!("Type \"quit\" if you wish to stop the game");
    println!("Please enter your first guess :")
}
```

**EDIT n°1, 30/03/2022**

- The colors are not represented by i32 anymore, it is now an enum called GamePegColor
- Created GamePeg Struct to hold the color and the state of a peg
- The state is a CodePeg enum (Correct, Missplaced, Wrong)
- Separated computation (compare_hands) and check if game is finished (check_in_finished) in 2 functions (previously the logic of check if game is finished was in the main)

I put on some comments in the code, but here is a summarize :

1. I created a default constructor for GamePeg but can't use it to initialize the static DEFAULT_HAND, how can I do ?
2. I'm not familiar with the Traits like `#[derive(Debug)]`, is this the correct way to use them ?
3. Does it feel clearer when you read the code now that there is a enum for the colors ?
4. I feel that it is a bit less optimized since I have to iterate through the list again in check_if_finished(), is that a problem ? Is there a better solution ?
5. To compare a variable with an enum value what is better between using `match` or `==` with `#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]` ?

New code :

````
use rand::Rng;
use std::io;

const NUMBER_OF_PEGS : usize = 4;
const NUMBER_OF_COLORS : i32 = 6;
const MAX_TURN : i32 = 12;
//QUESTION : How to have a static default constructor for GamePeg ?
//A call to GamePeg::default() does not copile : error[E0015]: calls in statics are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants
static DEFAULT_HAND : [GamePeg;NUMBER_OF_PEGS] = [GamePeg{color:GamePegColor::Unknown,state:CodePeg::Wrong};NUMBER_OF_PEGS as usize];

//------------------------------------------------

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]
#[derive(Debug)]
enum GamePegColor {
    White,
    Orange,
    Blue,
    Red,
    Yellow,
    Green,
    Unknown
}

impl GamePegColor {
    fn from_i32(value: i32) -> GamePegColor {
        match value {
            0 => GamePegColor::White,
            1 => GamePegColor::Orange,
            2 => GamePegColor::Blue,
            3 => GamePegColor::Red,
            4 => GamePegColor::Yellow,
            5 => GamePegColor::Green,
            _ => GamePegColor::Unknown
        }
    }

    fn from_str(value: &str) -> GamePegColor {
        let lower_cased : String = value.to_lowercase();
        match lower_cased.trim() {
            "white" => GamePegColor::White,
            "orange" => GamePegColor::Orange,
            "blue" => GamePegColor::Blue,
            "red" => GamePegColor::Red,
            "yellow" => GamePegColor::Yellow,
            "green" => GamePegColor::Green,
            _ => GamePegColor::Unknown
        }
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------

//QUESTION : Why is this not a default Trait ?
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum CodePeg {
    Correct,
    Missplaced,
    Wrong
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct GamePeg {
    color : GamePegColor,
    state : CodePeg
}

impl Default for GamePeg {
    fn default() -> Self {
        GamePeg {
            color:GamePegColor::Unknown,
            state:CodePeg::Wrong
        }
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------


fn main() {
    //Generate master's hand
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let master:[GamePegColor;NUMBER_OF_PEGS] = [(); NUMBER_OF_PEGS].map(|_| GamePegColor::from_i32(rng.gen_range(0..NUMBER_OF_COLORS)));
    let mut count = 1;
    print_rules();
    //print_line(master); //Debug only

    loop {
        println!("--- TURN n°{} ---",count);
        let (mut user_hand, stop) = get_user_hand();
        if stop { break;}

        let same_hands = compare_hands(&master,&mut user_hand);
        if same_hands {
            println!("You won ! The solution was :");
            print_line(master);
            break;
        }
        else if count == MAX_TURN {
            println!("You lost ! The solution was :");
            print_line(master);
            break;
        }
        count+=1;
    }
    
}

//Prints [GamePegColor,NUMBER_OF_PEGS]
fn print_line(list:[GamePegColor;NUMBER_OF_PEGS]) {
    println! ("{:?}", list);
}

//Returns user's hand as [GamePeg;NUMBER_OF_PEGS] and a stop bool that is true is the user asked to quit
fn get_user_hand() -> ([GamePeg;NUMBER_OF_PEGS],bool) {
    //Get user input
    let mut guess = String::new();

    loop {
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut guess)
            .expect("Failed to read line");

        if guess.trim().eq("quit"){
            return (DEFAULT_HAND,true);
        }

        let (user_hand, error) = parse_user_input(&guess);

        if !error {
            return (user_hand,false);
        } else {
            println!("You should enter {} colors (white, orange, blue, green, yellow or red)",NUMBER_OF_PEGS);
            println!("Type \"quit\" if you wish to stop the game");
            guess.clear();
        }
    }
}

//Parses the user hand, from a ¹str to a list of GamePeg
fn parse_user_input(guess:&str) -> ([GamePeg;NUMBER_OF_PEGS],bool) {
    let split = guess.split(' ');
    let mut array = [GamePeg::default();NUMBER_OF_PEGS];

    //Parse each number, stop if there are letters or out of range numbers
    let mut i = 0;
    for s in split {
        let peg_color : GamePegColor = GamePegColor::from_str(s);

        //QUESTION : When to use match ? when to use this ?
        if peg_color == GamePegColor::Unknown {return (DEFAULT_HAND,true);}

        if i >= NUMBER_OF_PEGS{
            break;
        }
        array[i].color=peg_color;
        i+=1;
    }
    let len_ok : bool = i >= NUMBER_OF_PEGS;
    if len_ok {
        return (array,false)
    } else 
    {
        return (DEFAULT_HAND,true)
    };
}

//Compares the user'hand with the master's code and returns true if they are the same
//QUESTION : Is it better to have the state of a peg in the GamePeg struct ? It has to be passed as &mut, which seems more complicated
fn compare_hands(master:&[GamePegColor;NUMBER_OF_PEGS],user:&mut[GamePeg;NUMBER_OF_PEGS]) -> bool{
    let len = master.len();
    let mut master_treated : [i32;NUMBER_OF_PEGS] = [0; NUMBER_OF_PEGS];
    let mut user_treated : [i32;NUMBER_OF_PEGS] = [0; NUMBER_OF_PEGS];

    //Computes correct
    for i in 0..len {
        if user[i].color==master[i] && master_treated[i]==0 {
            user[i].state=CodePeg::Correct;
            master_treated[i]=1;
            user_treated[i]=1;
        }
    }
    
    //Computes missplaced
    for i in 0..len {
        for j in 0..len{
            if master_treated[j]==0 && user_treated[i]==0 && user[i].color==master[j] {
                user[i].state=CodePeg::Missplaced;
                master_treated[j]=1;
                user_treated[i]=1;
            }
        }
    }

    return check_if_finished(user);
}

//QUESTION : seems less performant as before since I have to iterate through the list again, but is it cleaner ?
fn check_if_finished(user:&[GamePeg;NUMBER_OF_PEGS]) -> bool{
    let len = user.len();
    let mut correct = 0;
    let mut missplaced = 0;
    for i in 0..len{
        match user[i].state {
            CodePeg::Correct=>correct+=1,
            CodePeg::Missplaced=>missplaced+=1,
            _ => {}
        }
    }
    let finished = correct==NUMBER_OF_PEGS;
    if !finished{
        println!("N° of correct pegs: {}, n° of missplaced pegs: {}", correct, missplaced);
    }
    finished    
}

fn print_rules() {
    let mut format = String::new();
    for i in 0..NUMBER_OF_PEGS{
        let num = format!("white{}", if i!=NUMBER_OF_PEGS-1 {" "} else {""});
        format.push_str(&num);
    }
    println!("--- Mastermind ---");
    println!("- Rules :");
    println!("-     Find the master's code, made up of {} colors (white, orange, blue, green, yellow or red)",NUMBER_OF_PEGS);
    println!("-     You have 12 tries, if you fail to discover the master's code in less than 12 tries you loose");
    println!("-     At each turn, you enter your guess in the format \"{}\" (your colors are to be seperated by a space)",format);
    println!("-     The master will give you a hint about how close is your guess from his code with pins :");
    println!("-         - A correct peg means that one of the peg you chose is of the right color and is in the right spot");
    println!("-         - A missplaced peg means that one of the peg you chose is of the right color, but not at the right spot");
    println!("-     Good luck !");
    println!("You should enter {} colors (white, orange, blue, green, yellow or red)",NUMBER_OF_PEGS);
    println!("Type \"quit\" if you wish to stop the game");
    println!("Please enter your first guess :")
}
```
````

Comment: this is the game that many times the new wordle game is based on. Im not going to comment more than saying that using arrays with numbers many times is memory efficient, it makes the program many times hard to follow. But i would recommend watching jon gjengsets latest stream where he implements a wordle solver as it has many similarities with the logic you are trying to solve.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=doFowk4xj7Q

Comment: for instance i would define a peg as a struct containing a color. And the colors would be defined as enums. Then when iterating through and trying to figure out you have two arrays, one array that contains the states, if a peg is CORRECT, MISSPLACED or WRONG. And also have an array containing boolans keeping track if a peg has been evaluated or not. Also i would have like to see some unit testing of the logic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I like the idea of incorporating a state in the peg structure. i thought about using an enum for the colors but did not because it would be harder to parse user input, but maybe not in the end. It should be even clearer. I will implement this in the next days and update this post when I'm done. How should I update ? Modify my post and put the new code below the previous one ?

Comment: I would sugest updating your current post

Comment: I updated the post with the new version